# How Select Data and Insert data to another table using same stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I want to select some data inside a stored procedure and I want to insert all selected data to another table inside the same stored procedure:

```
SELECT * FROM @TempTable
```

then insert into another table like this:

```
SELECT @v_Maxno = isnull(max([A_TEST].ROW_NUM) + 1, 1)
        FROM [A_TEST]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[A_TEST] (ROW_NUM,A, B, C)  
VALUES (@v_Maxno,TempTable.CL_A, TempTable.CL_B, TempTable.CL_C)
```

I have to calculate row number Manually if any thing like loop so I will manage to achieve this.

Not finding the best way to doing this ..........Using SQL Server

Comment: correct insert statement as `INSERT INTO [dbo].[A_TEST] (A,B,C)   
    select CL_A, CL_B, CL_C from @TempTable `

Comment: I want to this row by row because there are some column in which i have to calculate the values like maxrow now etc

Comment: edit the question add some more details

Comment: Now I have added more details to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using values keyword, directly use select.

like this

```
insert into Table1(RowNum,Col1,Col2)
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Cola),Cola,colb from table2
```

Comment: I want to this row by row because there are some column in which i have to calculate the values like maxrow now etc .....

Comment: you can give it to the select itself, or add more details to the question

Comment: Now I have added more details to my question

Comment: I Don't want to Use Auto generated row Number

Comment: then instead of row_number() declare a variable of your choice, fetch the records inside a cursor of loop, increment the variable when needed